# add a c# library project to my project and how to use it

Tags: c#, winforms

i have c# library project. i add it`(library.sln)` as a existing project to my project. so it comes to my solution explorer.

but in my forms when i try to access it, it seems it dose not exist `using library;` is noting !
where am i wrong, and what i need to do ?

it can not be build itself in visual studio when i try to debug project, the error is :

```
a project with an output type of class library can not be started directly
```

you can see the library project here `http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/FarsiLibrary.aspx?msg=4043318#xx4043318xx` and it have 4 namespace.

Comment: You need to add the reference of that .dll file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "Set as StartUp Project" option in your context menu to set a runnable project. The project "library" you created is probably a class library which is not runnable.

Create some runnable project e.g. Condole application to use your library and set that as startup project. Then run your project.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the Set as StartUp Project which complements the reference problem

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not add an .sln to another solution. Add the Project (.csproj) instead.
2. When 2 projects are in the same solution there still is no link by default. Use Add Reference in the importing project.
3. Set an executable project as the Startup project.

Comment: i just have the `.sln` is it a problem ?

Comment: Look further, it should contain (refer to) a Project. Open the Solution and you can see where the Project file is.

Comment: The .sln will reference other .csprojs.  You can view their locations by viewing the .sln in notepad or a similar text editor.

Answer (score 0):

A library is just a collection of classes, interfaces, enums etc..  In order to debug it, you'll probably want to create a console application that calls methods on your classes that you want to debug.

In addition, just adding the library to the solution is not enough for other libraries to be able to see them.  In order to do this, you have to add it as a reference.  You can do this by right clicking on the References item in your project, then Add Reference.

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on your references folder, press "add reference", switch to "projects" and add the reference to your library project.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add the project to your solution, you have to add a reference to that project for the WinForms project. This has nothing to do with the library.

If your WinForms uses .NET 4 Client Profile and the library requires .NET Full, then you can't access it and need to change the WinForms project to use the full .NET 4 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers, but I would also suggest creating a **Test project** as a more efficient way of debugging the library.